# Office.context.mailbox.getUserIdentityTokenAsync. Including user groups

Tags: jwt, token, outlook-addin

How do i get the user groups to be returned as part of the jwt token when calling
`Office.context.mailbox.getUserIdentityTokenAsync`

I have already done the token configuration and re-consented as admin. But the id token does not include the group claims. Or any custom claims for that matter. What am i doing wrong?

[image]